# Possible to have background program in .NET?

Tags: .net, static, com

Is it possible to register a static class in COM and have its' static fields populated for later reference in .NET programs?

Comment: I know this is slightly vague, but I only need a vague answer guys.

Comment: Your title asks one question but the body asks another. Please rephrase one or both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. You can however mimic the desired behavior by creating an instance of the COM object inside a static class and delegating its properties:

```
public static class CoClassWrapper
{
    static CoClassWrapper()
    { 
        m_objCoCls = new CoClassImpl();
    }

    public static int m_nID
    {
        get { return m_objCoCls.m_nID; }
        set { m_objCoCls.m_nID = value; }
    }

    private static CoClassImpl m_objCoCls;
}
```